# Where to set timeout value for website?

Tags: iis

I have a website that has its own application pool and uses ASP.net. The application interfaces with a SQL database. I changed the IIS timeout value from 20 minutes to 30 minutes but it still tinmes out at 20 minutes. If I set the IIS, ASP, and apppool timeouts all to 30 minutes it works correctly. Is there a single place I can set the timeout value or do I need to set the timeout in all three locations?

Comment: Did you restart IIS and the relevant other services?

Answer (score 1):

If you're having specific issues with the database, you should be able to just worry about the app pool settings.

In general, you'll want to set them in all three places since all three items are handling different aspects of the application.

IIS is handling the general web interaction of the user.
ASP.Net is handling the specific scripting generation of pages for the user.
The app pool is handling the database connections.